# Change to date format

Tags: r

I have some data with a date column:

[image]

The format here is month-year. However this column is in a factor format and I need it as a date.

```
> str(data$date)
 Factor w/ 211 levels "01-1994","01-1996",..: 88 157 125 137 139 106 11 204 45 173 ...
```

I tried to change it this way but the outcome was a column of NA's. Where is the error?

```
data$date <- as.Date(data$date, format = "%m-%Y")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have dates.  You have a *factor variable* as `str()` tells you.

More generally, looks into `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`, either as an option to data reading (including from data base) or a global option.

For the issue at hand:  combine

```
as.Date(paste0(as.character(date$date), "-01"), "%m-%Y-%d")
```

as you also need a day to create a valid date.

Comment: I don't think the `as.character` is required here. `paste` *should* take care of that for you.

Comment: Good catch. Usually I do not need to add a "day".  Generally speaking one needs the `as.character()` to convert from factors, but here it extra fluff as you note.

Answer (score 3):

You may consider looking into the "zoo" package which has a `yearmon` format:

```
## Some sample data
test <- data.frame(date = c("05-2010", "09-2007", "01-2013"))
str(test)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  1 variable:
#  $ date: Factor w/ 3 levels "01-2013","05-2010",..: 2 3 1
```

Converting to `yearmon`:

```
library(zoo)
as.yearmon(test$date, format="%m-%Y")
# [1] "May 2010" "Sep 2007" "Jan 2013"
```

---

FYI: It is possible to wrap `as.yearmon` in `as.Date` if you need the regular date format.

```
as.Date(as.yearmon(test$date, format="%m-%Y"))
# [1] "2010-05-01" "2007-09-01" "2013-01-01"
```