# [r]Change objects into date format: Character (0) is the outcome + How to deal with missing values

Tags: r, date

I have searched stack overflow for this problem and there are a couple of solutions but none of them work for me as most solutions only work for short and complete data sets. I have two columns that are both 481029 rows long. They both contain dates in the form of dd.mm.YYYY. One is the order date and one is the delivery date. The aim is to calculate the difference (=deliverydate - orderdate). The problem is that some of the dates are missing in both columns. So sometimes there is a delivery date but no corresponding order date and vice versa. 1. How do I handle this? 2. How can I convert the data into the date form? My results are:

```
ddate <- data.frame(data$deliveryDate)
> summary(ddate)
  data.deliveryDate 
?         : 39419  
2013-04-04:  5285  
2012-07-03:  5079  
1990-12-31:  4660  
2013-01-01:  4585  
2013-04-09:  4565  
(Other)   :417499  
> class(ddate)
[1] "data.frame"
> ddate <- factor()
> as.Date(ddate, format= "%d.%m.%Y")
character(0)
> mean(ddate-odate)
[1] NaN
Warning message:
In Ops.factor(ddate, odate) : ‘-’ ist nicht sinnvoll für Faktoren
> class(ddate)
[1] "factor"
> ddate[1]
[1] <NA>
as.POSIXct(ddate)
character(0)
> ddate[1]
[1] <NA>
Levels: 
> as.Date(ddate, format= "%d.%m.%Y")
character(0)
>class(odate)
[1] "factor"
> as.Date(ddate, format = "%d.%m.%Y")
character(0)
> class(ddate)
[1] "factor"
> ddate <- as.Date(ddate, format = "%d.%m.%Y")
> class(ddate)
[1] "Date"
> odate <- as.Date(odate, format = "%d.%m.%Y")
> summary(odate)
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 NA      NA      NA      NA      NA      NA 
> head(odate)
character(0)
> mean(ddate-odate)
Time difference of NaN days
> ddate
character(0)
> str(ddate)
Class 'Date'  num(0) 
> str(odate)
Class 'Date'  num(0) 
> difftime(ddate,odate, units = ("days"))
Time difference of  days
```

I hope that this is not too messy and confusing. I just tried many things but I don't get it. The outcome is alway NA or something like this...
Thank you all!

Comment: The date variables have been converted into factors. Use as.is=TRUE when reading in your data via `read.csv` or friends. They will then be read in as characters and you can apply the `as.Date` function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change to date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100789/change-to-date-format)

Comment: You might want to use ``difftime(datevector2, datevector1)`` if you properly formatted you're datevectors.

Comment: Thank you lmo and Phann!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, follow lmo 's advice to read all columns as characters.

Coming to your first question, you can get rid of ? using this:

```
data$deliveryDate <- ifelse(data$deliveryDate == '?',NA,data$deliveryDate)

data$orderDate <- ifelse(data$orderDate == '?',NA,data$orderDate)

indices <- complete.cases(data)

final.data <- data[indices,]
```

If you apply this thing, only those rows will appear in the dataset `final.data` which have both delivery and order date.

You need not specify the format in as.Date here.

Plus if you have shown the deliveryDate values correctly, it is not of the format dd.mm.YYYY

At the end, use Phann's advice to find the difference

**Update:**

That's the code you are required to write:

```
## now, no need to check for '?' as it will be treated as NA .
data<-read.table("datatxt.txt", header=TRUE, sep = ";", stringsAsFactors = F, na.strings='?') 

final_data <- data[complete.cases(data),]

final_data$deliveryDate <- as.Date(final_data$deliveryDate)

final_data$orderDate <- as.Date(final_data$orderDate)
```

After this, you can apply the remaining operations.

If efficiency is required, you can use this code:

```
library(data.table)
## now, no need to check for '?' as it will be treated as NA .
data<-fread("datatxt.txt", na.strings='?') 

final_data <- data[complete.cases(data),]

final_data[,deliveryDate := as.Date(deliveryDate)]

final_data[,orderDate := as.Date(orderDate)]
```

Comment: Thank you first of all! I have read the .txt data now and it stayed now in character form and did not change to factor. That's good. What do you mean with I don't have to specify the format as in as.Date here? The format dd.mm.YYYY is shown when I open it with Excel. Do I have to use as.Date(file, format ="%Y-%m-%d")? Do you think the format here is YYYY-mm-dd ?

Comment: I have another problem: Some values of data$deliveryDate are wrong. They show 31.12.1990 as the date which cannot be as the orders were made in 2012. How can I tell r to ignore also these rows where data$deliveryDate = 31.12.1990?

Comment: Excel may format it in its own way. Look at the data with an editor and you will see how the data is stored. If the date is in standard form, you don't have to specify it, otherwise you have to. You could exclude dates e.g. with: ``data[which(data$deliveryDate > as.Date("2000-01-01)), ]``, which just returns these rows where deliveryDate is greater than the year 2000.

Comment: @Vinc Answering to your first question, As it is the default format used by R, you need not specify it. And the format doesn't contain any dots. Because when you are applying summary() function in the mentioned output, no dots appear there.

Comment: Absolutely Correct advice by @Phann.

Comment: Ok thank you. Now what I have done is:<code>      > data<-read.table("datatxt.txt", header=TRUE, sep = ";", as.is = TRUE) ,    > odate <- as.Date(data$orderDate)
> head(odate)
[1] "2012-04-01" "2012-04-01" "2012-04-01" "2012-04-02" "2012-04-02" "2012-04-02"
> ddate <- as.Date(data$deliveryDate)
> str(ddate)
 Date[1:481092], format: "2012-04-03" "2012-04-03" "2012-04-03" NA "1990-12-31" "1990-12-31" ...
> ddate <- ifelse(ddate == "?", NA, ddate)
Error in charToDate(x) : </code>
  (something like that the character string is not in standard format). What now?

Comment: Hope one of you can help me @Kunal Puri

Comment: I just saw that the data already contains "NA" and not "?". You can see it in the commentary where I wrote > str(ddate)

Comment: @Vinc I have updated the solution. Please do have a look.

Comment: And data doesn't contain NA. When you are casting ? to Date, it is producing NA.

Comment: Thank you very much @KunalPuri . The file data also contains more colums than just the orderDate and the deliveryDate. But I don't need them for now as I just want the difference between these dates. How can tell r to ignore them or to use only orderDate and deliveryDate?

Comment: @Vinc I don't think you can tell R to ignore the remaining columns. But if you want to have only orderDate and deliveryDate columns in the dataset, you can create a separate data.frame by `new_data <- data[,c('orderDate','deliveryDate')]` (for `data.table` you need to use `new_data <- data[,c('orderDate','deliveryDate'),with=F]`)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. This is what the final result looks like:

```
 > data<-read.table("datatxt.txt", header=TRUE, sep = ";", stringsAsFactors = F, na.strings='?') # read the file and treat all "?" as NA 
> dates <- data[,c('orderDate','deliveryDate')] # only use the orderDate and deliveryDate columns from the data set "data" 

> final_dates <- dates[complete.cases(dates),] # only use the rows which are complete in both columns
> final_dates$deliveryDate <- as.Date(final_dates$deliveryDate) #define as Date
> final_dates$orderDate <- as.Date(final_dates$orderDate) # define as Date
> deliverytime <- difftime(final_dates$deliveryDate, final_dates$orderDate, units = c("days")) # calculate the difference of the dates in days
> deliverytime_wo_1990 <- subset(deliverytime, deliverytime>0) # only show positive days. To get rid of wrong data where the deliverydate is before the orderdate. 
> mean(deliverytime_wo_1990) # finally it is possible to calculate for example the mean!
```

Thanks everybody. I finally made it.